# Applying grammar to strings

Tags: c#, string, grammar, console.writeline

I'm trying to make the genetive of the inserted name be decided automatically so that I won't have to manually insert the proper genetive for each string (in this case names)

As an example the genetive for James is ' and the genetive for Kennedy is 's.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that I want a cleaner implementation that allows me to skip having to write string Genetive:friend1(2..n) for each name

```
using System;

namespace Prac
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Friend =  "";                string last_char_Friend = "";               string Genetive_Friend = "";
            string Friend1 = "Kennedy";         string last_char_Friend1 = Friend1[^1..];   string Genetive_Friend1 = "\'s";    
            string Friend2 = "James";           string last_char_Friend2 = Friend2[^1..];   string Genetive_Friend2 = "\'";
            string Friend3 = "Ngolo Kante";     string last_char_Friend3 = Friend3[^1..];   string Genetive_Friend3 = "\'s";

        Console.WriteLine($"My friends are named {Friend1}, {Friend2} and {Friend3}");

        Console.WriteLine($"{Friend1}{Genetive_Friend1} name has {Friend1.Length} letters");
        Console.WriteLine($"{Friend2}{Genetive_Friend2} name has {Friend2.Length} letters");
        Console.WriteLine($"{Friend3}{Genetive_Friend3} name has {Friend3.Length} letters");

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Friend + i}{Genetive_Friend + i} name has {(Friend + i).Length} letters");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

There simply must be a smarter way for me to ensure that proper grammar is applied to each name, I've got a feeling that I can utilize reading the last char of the Friend string, but how do I within Console.WriteLine pick betweem ' and 's?

I'd like the for loop to print the same as the three individual Console.WriteLine lines.

Also this is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow, please tell me if I've broken some unwritten rule on how questiosn should be formatted.

Comment: You could write a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a few questions here, firstly to loop through all the arguments you should create an Array (Or list or really anything extending [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0))
then you can iterate over it.

now following your example and not being particularly versed in grammar you can also write a method to check what is the last character of the input string and convert it into the genitive case

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{

    string[] friends = new string[] { "Kennedy", "James", "Ngolo Kante" };
    Console.WriteLine($"My friends are named {JoinEndingWithAnd(friends)}");
    for ( int i = 1; i < friends.Length; i++ )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( $"{MakeGenitive(friends[i])} name has {friends[i].Length} letters" );
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string JoinEndingWithAnd(string[] friends)
{
    string result = friends[0];

    for ( int i = 1; i < friends.Length; i++ )
    {
        if ( i != friends.Length  - 1)
        {
            result += $" , {friends[i]}";
        }
        else
        {
            result += $" and {friends[i]}";
        }
    }

    return result;
}

static string MakeGenitive(string friend)
{
    char lastLetter = friend[^1];
    
    if( lastLetter == 's' )
    {
        return friend + "'";
    }
    return friend + "'s";
}
```